# Problema com instalação do Meteor no windows

Tags: javascript, windows, meteor

Meu é um windows 7 e quando instalo o meteor pelo próprio instalador dele, quando executo o comando meteor acontece esse erro

```
C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.5.0\mt-os.windows.x86_3 2\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\q\q.js:70
    hasStacks = !!e.stack;
                   ^
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

Alguém poderia me informar porque esta dando esse erro.

Comment: você **não** postou o erro, mas creio que seja o erro `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`, estou certo?

Comment: Sim esse mesmo.

Comment: Não precisava editar eu já tinha adicionado o erro exatamente como é exibido. Estou olhando o github deles, parece ser um bug mesmo.